# Why does my AWS SAM Lambda fails to access an S3 bucket locally but is successful when deployed?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sam

I have an AWS Lambda using AWS Textract. So far I used a local file to test if everything works but now I want to switch to fetching the file from an S3 bucket.

I changed the code to do that and then I try `sam local invoke` but it gives me the error that I cannot access this bucket because I lack permission:

```
 Invoke Error    {"errorType":"InvalidS3ObjectException","errorMessage":"Unable to get object metadata from S3. Check object key, region and/or access permissions.","code":"InvalidS3ObjectException","message":"Unable to get object metadata from S3. Check object key, region and/or access permissions."
```

I checked and I have added the necessary permissions to my Lambda. I deployed the lambda and it worked when deployed so the problem is only locally and I want it to work locally so that I can test it before actually deploying.

Here is my AWS SAM Template:

```yaml
    AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
    Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
    Description: >
      documentProcessing

      Sample SAM Template for documentProcessing
      
    # More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
    Globals:
      Function:
        Timeout: 15

    Parameters:
      Environment:
        Type: String
        AllowedValues:
          - develop
          - product
        Default: develop

    Resources:
      DocumentProcessingFunction:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
        Properties:
          CodeUri: document-processing/
          Handler: app.lambdaHandler
          Runtime: nodejs14.x
          Architectures:
            - x86_64
          Events:
            DocumentProcessing:
              Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
              Properties:
                Path: /document
                Method: get
```

How do I resolve that? How can I make it access the S3 bucket locally?

Comment: When you run `sam local invoke` you need to supply a local AWS credentials profile via `--profile name` and that profile needs to be associated with credentials that have the relevant permissions. Afaik, sam local won't assume the IAM role that's indicated for the Lambda function in your template (because the code's not running in AWS Lambda).

Comment: Yes, this worked for me. I just never could find in the official documentation that I can use `--profile` with `sam local invoke`. Thank you a lot.